# rvest on extracting link within <a rel= ... href=>

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors, rvest

I'm trying to use `rvest` package to scrape a list of links embedded on a page. Before I'd use something like this:

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("link")
page %>% html_nodes('{a href}') %>% html_attr('href')
```

However, this only gives me the link related to `<a href="https://www.abcefg.com">Here</a>` but not this link `<a rel="external nofollow noopener" href="www.dropbox.com/abcdefg.rar" "target="_blank">Part 01</a>`

My question is how to get the second link while ignore the first link?

Comment: Did you use _html_nodes('a [href]')_ ? And not sure with r but you may not get links in head of response.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath, perhaps `//a[@rel]` should help (it selects all `a` elements with an attribute `rel`).